# Maxwell's Equations Curl Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

$$\left\{ \begin{align} \text{div } \textbf{E} &=0, \\ \text{div } \textbf{H} & =0, \\ \text{curl } \textbf{E} & = \dfrac{-1}{c} \dfrac{\partial\textbf{H}}{\partial t}, \\\text{curl } \textbf{H} & =\dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{\partial\textbf{E}}{\partial t}, \end{align} \right.$$ where $c$ is the speed of light.

Using the equations above, and the assumption that $\textbf{E}$ and $\textbf{H}$ are infinitely differentiable, show that the following identity holds true.

$$\nabla \text{x}(\nabla \text{x} \textbf{E})= \dfrac{-1}{c}\dfrac{\partial^2\textbf{E}}{\partial t^2}$$

$$\nabla \text{x} \textbf{E} =\dfrac{-1}{c}\dfrac{\partial\textbf{H}}{\partial t}$$

$$\nabla \text{x} \left(\dfrac{-1}{c}\dfrac{\partial\textbf{H}}{\partial t}\right) = \dfrac{-1}{c} \left(\nabla \text{x} \dfrac{\partial \textbf{H}}{\partial t}\right) $$

$$=\dfrac{-1}{c} \left( \dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{\partial^2\textbf{E}}{\partial t^2} \right)$$

$$=\dfrac{-1}{c^2} \dfrac{\partial^2\textbf{E}}{\partial t^2}$$

Could someone please correct this if it's wrong? I don't know if taking the curl of a derivative equals the derivative of the curl...if not, I don't know how else to prove this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the space and time derivatives commute so you can exchange curl and $\partial/\partial t$. This follows from [Schwarz' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem) which tells you that if a function has continuous second partial derivatives at any point (which $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ do since they are infinitely differentiable) then you can exchange the order of partial differentiation.

Comment: This does not really have anything to do with Schwarz's theorem because the curl is not a derivative but rather the exterior derivative.

Comment: @Fantini take the first component, we have
$$
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial H_z}{\partial t} -  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \frac{\partial H_y}{\partial t} \right)
$$
How do we know that we can "factor" the time derivative out here?

Comment: @DanZimm, if you can't factor derivatives, is my solution incorrect?

Comment: @user7000 the point is you *can* factor derivatives in this case so your solution is correct. See here for example: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=k046p9v-ZCgC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=curl+and+time+derivative+commute&source=bl&ots=CbS2RmJIw3&sig=36ccUHFtcutS8PeLY7BQ4a2THes&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n8zLU4nGGIfA0QWJv4CQBw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=curl%20and%20time%20derivative%20commute&f=false

Comment: @DanZimm I guess I got carried away because he wrote $d/dt$. The answer to your question is, of course, Schwarz's theorem.

Comment: @ozo Thanks for the link.

Comment: @user7000 correct, but you can, so you're good to go!

Comment: @Fantini I just checked out your profile, I'm guessing you know some differential geometry, I think this is a bit simpler of a situation ;D

Comment: @DanZimm I know a little bit, just enough to make wrong comments and leave no doubt of how little I know hahaha. =)